# Is there any area where Threads should be favored over Coroutines?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I just gave a talk about Kotlin's Coroutines and the question arised if Coroutines can always replace Threads or if there also might be disadvantages.

Or the other way round: Is there any area where Coroutines should not be used for?

Comment: If you run your coroutines on a single thread, then you'll be limited to single-threaded performance for workloads that aren't IO-bound.  If you get round this limit by running coroutines across multiple threads, then you're back to threads :)

Comment: Co-routines are useful in one specific corner of the solution space. Multi-threading covers a much larger area of the solution space. There is minimal overlap between the solutions requiring multiple threads and co-routines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coroutines are useful for asynchronous programming. When you are writing code that has to wait most of the time for some external events, like it often happens in modern connected user-interfaces and micro-service-oriented backend applications, then coroutines and the concept of Kotlin suspending functions let you write naturally looking and easy-to-understand code that is more scalable than the code with explicit threads.

If you are writing some kind of computation, CPU-intensive code, then you'd find that classical patterns of multithread-programming and parallelism work better.

It does not mean that you cannot use coroutines to parallelize some piece of CPU-intensive application, but you will not get any benefits in either code readability or its performance from doing so.

Comment: Hey Roman! Thanks for coroutines, though I have hard times understanding the magic behind them, which makes using them quite dangerous. As soon as I understand the magic - I certainly will give them a try. This is just kind of feedback :-) I know you have had talks in Kotlin Conf concerning that topic.

Comment: Thanks. Take a look at my "Deep Dive into Coroutines" talk from KotlinConf. It gives enough information about implementation details to dispel all the magic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrrUCSi72E8

Comment: There's some middle ground as well: DAG-based computing with a model similar to Actors. It's very CPU-intensive, but individual workers get blocked when their output queue fills up. Then you find another worker to run. With hundreds or thousands of workers, performance is better with coroutines in a thread pool than with native threads. This is the architecture we use in Hazelcast Jet, and we already applied Kotlin coroutines to it as a prototype (in production we have a coroutine-like Java API). Kotlin worked great for us, 100% performance of Java!